Minimizing Perimeter of Rectangles Covering Marked Cells in a 2D Grid
I have a problem where I need to cover marked cells in a 2D grid using rectangular boxes, with the goal of minimizing the total perimeter of the boxes. The rectangles can overlap, and they can also cover empty cells, but all marked cells must be covered.
Problem Description:
Given a 2D grid $ G $ of size $ n \times m $, some cells in $ G $ are marked with crosses. The objective is to cover all the crossed cells using rectangular boxes, while minimizing the total perimeter of the rectangles.
The goal is to cover all the marked cells using the minimum possible total perimeter.
Input Representation:

The grid $ G $ is represented as a matrix of size $ n \times m $.
A rectangle $ B_i $ can be represented as a pair of ranges for $ x $ and $ y $:

$ B_i = ([x_{\text{min}}, x_{\text{max}}], [y_{\text{min}}, y_{\text{max}}]) $, where $ x_{\text{min}} \leq x_{\text{max}} $ and $ y_{\text{min}} \leq y_{\text{max}} $.



Each rectangle can cover both marked and unmarked cells, but the goal is to minimize the sum of perimeters of the rectangles.
Example:
Consider the following example with a 7x7 grid, represented in the image below. There are 10 marked cells ('X').

In this image:

One possible solution is to cover the marked cells with three rectangles:

Rectangle 1: A 2x4 box covering the crosses in the left area.
Rectangle 2: A 1x1 box for a cross in the upper-right.
Rectangle 3: A 2x2 box covering the crosses in the lower-right.



These three rectangles are defined as:

$ B_1 = ([1, 2], [2, 5]) $
$ B_2 = ([2, 2], [5, 5]) $
$ B_3 = ([5, 6], [4, 5]) $

Each rectangle's perimeter is:

Rectangle 1 (2x4): Perimeter = $ 2 \times (2 + 4) = 12 $
Rectangle 2 (1x1): Perimeter = $ 2 \times (1 + 1) = 4 $
Rectangle 3 (2x2): Perimeter = $ 2 \times (2 + 2) = 8 $

The total cost (sum of perimeters) for this configuration is:
$$
12 + 4 + 8 = 24
$$
However, an optimal solution would be to use a single 4x4 rectangle that covers all the crosses, with a perimeter of $ 2 \times (4 + 4) = 16 $, minimizing the total cost.
Mathematical Formulation:

Input:

A grid $ G $ of size $ n \times m $, where some cells are marked with crosses.


Output:

A set of rectangular boxes $ \{B_1, B_2, \dots, B_k\} $ that cover all the crosses.


Objective:

Minimize the total perimeter:
$$
 \sum_{i=1}^{k} 2 \times (\text{width of } B_i + \text{height of } B_i)
 $$




Question:

Is this problem known by a specific name in computer science or geometry?
What are some known algorithms or heuristic methods for solving this problem, or approximating a solution with minimal total perimeter?
Can dynamic programming, greedy algorithms, or any geometric covering techniques be effectively used for this problem?

Any guidance on the approach or references to related problems would be greatly appreciated.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_set_cover_problem

@D.W. The difference here is in my case, we want to minimize the sum of perimeters, not the box count. I don't see a clear way to convert this problem into geometric set cover.

I agree, it's not the same question.  I suppose it could be viewed as an instance of weighted geometric set cover, with a specific set of weights.  That doesn't answer your question, but I thought it might provide you an entrypoint into the published literature, which might be a place to start learning more about what is known.

FWIW, it should be sufficient to only consider solutions where rectangles do not overlap or share edges. For any solution where two rectangles overlap or share an edge, you can create a better solution by replacing the two rectangles by their minimum bounding rectangle.

Try to construct examples where the solution is not the minimum bounding box: How can you tell another box is better than enlarging an "existing" one?.
